# How can I apply a style to a div using CSS as long as that div does NOT contain an element with a certain id?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am writing a CSS stylesheet to add a background image to a div identified by its class name as follows:

```
.scrollingResultsContainer
{
    background-image: url(https://mdl0133/widget/Images/gradient.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

This works fine except I have one particular situation where I do not want the image to appear in the `scrollingResultsContainer`. How can I specify that the image should be applied except when the `scrollingResultsContainer` happens to contain a div with a particular id?

Unfortunately, I am unable to amend the markup to prevent this situation from occurring.
I was wondering if it can be done using CSS3 selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS. A parent selector has been proposed many times but is always rejected because apparently it's just too hard to code or something:
http://www.css3.info/shaun-inman-proposes-css-qualified-selectors/

You'll have to use javascript I'm afraid.

Comment: I thought I almost had it by declaring position on the scrollingResultsContainer and using a css before selector like: div#particular_id:before { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; background:#fff; content:""; } but it completely obliterates everything in the area; even stuff that comes after in the document.

Comment: :before adds a pseudo-element before the div, but does not apply to it's parent.

Comment: true. but you can style the pseudo element using absolute positioning to completely overlay the parent element. unfortunately it also overlays the element that it is applied to - which doesn't make sense to me if it is inserted before it.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did there. Nice thinking, but too bad indeed that it didn't work. Probably because it's absolute positioning..?

Answer (score 1):

CSS4 might make this possible in the future, see http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview.

Answer (score 0):

Over-ride it in the CSS if you know the ID in advance.

```
.scrollingResultsContainer {
    font-size: 200%;
}

#id_of_div {
    font-size: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am after. I need to reset the whole of the scrollingResultsContainer not just one particular div within it.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to do is prevent the image from showing up, this is fairly simple with CSS. You can use the `::before` pseudo-element on the child `<div>` to cover the image and `z-index` to get the layers right.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
.scrollingResultsContainer {
    background-image: url( 'http://placekitten.com/100' );
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -2;
}
.dont-show::before {
    background-color: white;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="scrollingResultsContainer"></div>
<div class="scrollingResultsContainer">
    <div class="dont-show">don't show</div>
</div>
<div class="scrollingResultsContainer"></div>
<div class="scrollingResultsContainer"></div>
```